# parents, children, recursive list, and method structure

Tags: php, oop, recursion

My goal is to display a family tree starting from **Person X** and showing all descendants. No need to show siblings, parents, or other ancestors.

To this end I have a `person` class.

I also have a database table with `person_ID` and `parent_ID` columns.

When the `person` class is created you pass it the desired person ID, then it will preload its parents and children IDs from that table.

In order to create the descendents tree I wrote the following method inside the `person` class:

```
public function loadChildren() {
    foreach ($this->_ChildIDs as $curChildID) {
        $child = new Person();
        $child->loadSelfFromID($curChildID);
        $child->loadChildren();
        $this->_Children[] = $child;
    }
}
```

This successfully recursively loads the entire tree of descendents.

So far so good.

In order to display this data as a nested HTML list I wrote the following standalone function:

```
function recursivePrint($array) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($array as $child) {
        echo '<li>'.$child->getName();
        recursivePrint($child->getChildren());
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

The final script then looks like this:

```
$c = new Person();
$c->loadSelfFromID('1');
$c->loadChildren(); // recursively loads all descendants
$descendants = $c->getChildren();
recursivePrint($descendants);

//Output is as expected.
```

My question is this: **where do I stick that standalone function?**

Does it just get tossed in a random utility include for functions that don't really go anywhere else? Should it go into the `person` class? Should it go into a `FamilyTree` class that only makes trees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [Composite Design Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite).

Here is another resource: http://devzone.zend.com/364/php-patterns_the-composite-pattern/

**EDIT**

```
class Person
{
    public $name;
    protected $_descendants = null;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->_descendants = array();
    }

    public function addDescendant(Person $descendant)
    {
        $i = array_search($descendant, $this->_descendants, true);

        if($i === false){
            $this->_descendants[] = $descendant;
        }
    }

    public function toString()
    {
        $str = $this->name;
        if(count($this->_descendants) > 0){

            $str .= PHP_EOL . '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;

            foreach($this->_descendants as $descendant){
                $str .= '<li>' .  $descendant->toString() . '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
            }
            $str .= '</ul>' . PHP_EOL;

        }
        return $str;
    }
}


$dad = new Person('Dad');
$dad->addDescendant(new Person('Big sister'));
$dad->addDescendant(new Person('Big brother'));
$dad->addDescendant(new Person('Little brat'));

$grandMa = new Person('GrandMa');

$grandMa->addDescendant($dad);

echo $grandMa->toString();
```

Comment: It's helpful to know the pattern's name, but those links don't touch on how to export the data into a nested list once it has been assembled, which is my primary problem.

Comment: To answer your specific concern, you won't need a stand-alone function as you call it. You simply would need to implement a method in your `Person` object that generates the `<ul>` list of a `Person` instance. On top of that, the method should also loop through its children and call the same method on each one of them to do the same task (which is producing a `<ul>` list for themselves, in your case.)