# Selected value in nested children array, need parent arrays to acquire value as well

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now and decided to turn to the great stackoverlow community for advice. I am asking for a solution to my problem but in knowing the solution I will learn a great deal.

I have an array as seen here

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [parent] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [parent] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [parent] => 3
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 7
                                            [parent] => 4
                                            [selected] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [parent] => 3
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [parent] => 3
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

As you can see array elements sometimes have nested "children", and those may have "children" etc etc etc but eventually you will come to an array with a value "SELECTED" = true. What I need is a way to make all of its parents become "SELECTED".

I have this function in PHP but it refuses to work. And now my brain is fried

```
private function selectParent($tree)
{
    foreach ($tree as $key => $branch) 
    {
        if(isset($branch['children']))
        {
            $tree[$key]['children'] = self::selectParent($tree[$key]['children']);
        }

        if(isset($branch['children']))
        {
            foreach ($branch['children'] as $child) 
            {
                if(isset($child['selected']))
                {
                    $tree[$key]['selected'] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Any help / tips / solutions very much appreciated.

Thanks
Martin

UPDATE

I updated my function to this and it works

```
private function selectParent($tree, $id = null)
{
    $newTree = array();

    foreach ($tree as $key => $branch) 
    {
        if(isset($branch['children']))
        {
            $branch['children'] = self::selectParent($branch['children']);
        }

        if(isset($branch['children']))
        {
            foreach ($branch['children'] as $child) 
            {
                if(isset($child['selected']))
                {
                    $branch['selected'] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        $newTree[] = $branch;
    }
    return $newTree;
}
```

I will however look into the suggested methods.
Thank you to those who replied to help out!

Comment: Please excuse my failed attempt at code blocks

Comment: Just as I was editing it an admin done it for me. Sorry and Thanks!

Comment: I highly doubt that it *"refuses to work"*

Comment: Okay it doesn't "refuse to work", my attempt at a solution failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This clearly is a task for recursion. Try the following:

```php
$data = [
    ['id' => 1, 'selected' => false, 'parent' => 0],
    ['id' => 2, 'selected' => false, 'parent' => 0, 'children' => [
        ['id' => 3, 'selected' => false, 'parent' => 2],
        ['id' => 4, 'selected' => false, 'parent' => 2, 'children' => [
            ['id' => 5, 'selected' => false, 'parent' => 4],
            ['id' => 6, 'selected' => false, 'parent' => 4],
            ['id' => 7, 'selected' => false, 'parent' => 4],
        ]]
    ]],
    ['id' => 8, 'selected' => false, 'parent' => 0],
];

function markSelectedBranch(&$data) {
    $hasSelectedChildren = false;

    foreach ($data as &$dataPoint) {
        if (isset($dataPoint['children'])) {
            $hasSelectedChildren = markSelectedBranch($dataPoint['children']);
            if ($hasSelectedChildren) {
                $dataPoint['selected'] = true;
            }
        }

        if (isset($dataPoint['selected']) && $dataPoint['selected']) {
            $hasSelectedChildren = true;
        }
    }

    return $hasSelectedChildren;
}

var_dump(markSelectedBranch($data));
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: I admit I don't know much about recursion so will do my research. Thank you for this suggestion! Much help!

Comment: This is definitely an improvement on my solution in my edit. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the one creating this mega complex array, I would suggest using OOP instead. You can create Objects that contain children. It'll be much easier to read and debug.

Here's an example of using recursive in an OOP way.

[PHP recursively traverse object tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108512/php-recursively-traverse-object-tree)

[Example of using classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php)

[parents, children, recursive list, and method structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068310/parents-children-recursive-list-and-method-structure)

If you insist on keeping this array structure, try echoing variables in your code to see where your problem lies.

```
private function selectParent($tree)
{
    foreach ($tree as $key => $branch) 
    {

        if(isset($branch['children']))
        {
            print_r($branch['children']);
            $tree[$key]['children'] = self::selectParent($tree[$key]['children']);
        }

        if(isset($branch['children']))
        {
            print_r($branch['children']);
            foreach ($branch['children'] as $child) 
            {
                print_r($child);
                if(isset($child['selected']))
                {
                    print_r($child['selected']);
                    $tree[$key]['selected'] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help Catfish.

Comment: Added a 3rd link that contains something similar to what you're trying to do.